# I made a for loop in python using Sublime Text from (1 to 99,999,999) to just print the number. Memory exceeded

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, out-of-memory, sublimetext3

I made a for loop in python using Sublime Text from (1 to 99,999,999) to just print the number.

for number in (1,99999999):
print(number)

It freezes, memory consumption goes to 45GB in like 1 minute.

I've tried looking for the file to delete it, because everytime I open sublime it freezes immediately, but I can't find it for the life of me. Tried uninstalling then reinstalling, but it just won't work.

Comment: What did you use to run it? The normal Python build or did you make your own?

Comment: Try searching your computer for an extremely large `.sublime-project` file, and delete it. What operating system do you use, and how did you install Sublime - through an installer, or as a portable install?

Comment: I'm following the Python crashcourse book. It mentioned to make my own build using this command:

{
.sublime-build "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
}

I tried searching .sublime-project, still nothing.

I'm really new to this, so I don't actually understand what you mean by intaller or portable install. I downloaded the latest version from their website then just double clicked the file and it opened.

Comment: You'll only find a project file if you made one, but they don't persist anything about your session (that is `sublime-workspace` files, which you would have to have created yourself if you're not using projects). Try starting Sublime in [Safe Mode](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/safe_mode.html) to see if the problem is related to the code you ran or not.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I entered safe mode, so the program didn't automatically run. Then I was able to remove the loop and reopened it normally.

Comment: @OdatNurd I mean `sublime-workspace`, my fingers just hit the wrong keys. Stupid fingers!